# What is the recommender address and his/her title or position in graduate applications?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I was trying to fill out the graduate school application for graduate school. However in the "recommender info" part it asks me to enter the address, city, institute and title or position but I wonder what they are? should I enter the university address? is title or position like assistant or full professor? 
I would be very appreciated if anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the person who will write the letter of recommendation what address they want you to use. I suspect that this university will send them a return envelope to use to submit the letter, so the address must be their proper mailing address.

Comment: I would guess that Stanford applications are completely online. In any case, when I was asked by a recommendee what my address was, I thought "Doesn't this person know how to look things up on the internet?" Perhaps this was unfair, but it was my first impression.

Comment: It was unfair. I would guess that your address is your name at you department's mailing address (which is on their site), but if Stanford needs an official address for you, why not help a student out by giving it to them?

Comment: I did give it to them, without complaint. I also don't complain to students who ask questions whose answers are on the syllabus. But grad schools are looking to admit students who are independent and who have the ability to take the initiative and discover things on their own. Asking a recommender for his/her address strikes me as a (very small) data point to the contrary.

Comment: @Anonymous: Some universities are _very_ labyrinthine and don't do a very good job with sorting mail. (Heaven knows how far my group's mail gets scattered across campus!) Asking might be a way to make sure you get the right information. You could ask the address I want to list for you is "X." Is this correct?

Comment: @Anonymous: Ridiculous. Aeismail's comment is spot on. Also, maybe graduate admissions committees also want to admin students who are diligent, precise, and exacting, in which case, verifying the address with the letter writer is a small data point in the plus column.

Answer (score 1):

These days, most people who could serve as a good recommender have a professional website that will give their full contact information, including their full title, mailing address, etc.  You can typically find this either by Google or by going to their organization's website, which will somewhere have a list of faculty and other significant staff.

If this information is not publicly online (most likely to happen with a recommender from a company) then just ask your recommender to give their preferred contact information.

Comment: I think the OP should not rely on the online information, because it has the risk of being outdated or being changed over the time. It's always the sure way to ask the recommender what is his precise contact information.

Comment: Usually, what actually matters is the email and phone, which departments are actually pretty good at keeping up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the mailing address for the academic department in question. This can be easily found on the department's website. And yes, position is something like assistant or associate professor.